# SQL query combine rows based on common id

Tags: sql, sql-server, row

I have a table with the below structure:

| MID | FromCountry | FromState | FromCity | FromAddress | FromNumber | FromApartment | ToCountry | ToCity | ToAddress | ToNumber | ToApartment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | USA | Texas | Houston | Well Street | 1 |  | Japan | Tokyo |  | 6 | ET3 |
| 123 | Germany | Bremen | Bremen | Nice Street | 4 |  | Poland | Warsaw |  | 9 | ET67 |
| 456 | France | Corsica | Corsica | Amz Street | 3 |  | Italy | Milan |  | 8 | AEC784 |
| 456 | UK | UK | London | G Street | 2 |  | Portugal | Lisbon |  | 1 | LP400 |

The desired outcome is:

| MID | FromCountry | FromState | FromCity | FromAddress | FromNumber | FromApartment | ToCountry | ToCity | ToAddress | ToNumber | ToApartment | FromCountry1 | FromState1 | FromCity1 | FromAddress1 | FromNumber1 | FromApartment1 | ToCountry1 | ToCity1 | ToAddress1 | ToNumber1 | ToApartment1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | USA | Texas | Houston | Well Street | 1 |  | Japan | Tokyo |  | 6 | ET3 | Germany | Bremen | Bremen | Nice Street | 4 |  | Poland | Warsaw |  | 9 | ET67 |
| 456 | France | Corsica | Corsica | Amz Street | 3 |  | Italy | Milan |  | 8 | AEC784 | UK | UK | London | G Street | 2 |  | Portugal | Lisbon |  | 1 | LP400 |

What I am trying to achieve is to bring multiple rows in 1 table, which have the same MID, under 1 row, regardless if there are columns with empty values.

I think that i over complicated the                 solution to this as I was trying            something like this (and of course the outcome is not the desired one):

```sql
select [MID],
    STUFF(
        (select concat('', [FromCountry]) 
        FROM test i
        where i.[MID] = o.[MID]
        for xml path ('')),1,1,'') as FromCountry
    ,stuff (
        (select concat('', [FromState]) 
        FROM test i
        where i.[MID] = o.[MID]
        for xml path ('')),1,1,'') as FromState
    ,stuff (
        (select concat('', [FromCity]) 
        FROM test i
        where i.[MID] = o.[MID]
        for xml path ('')),1,1,'') as FromCity
    ,stuff (
        (select concat('', [FromAddress]) 
        FROM test i
        where i.[MID] = o.[MID]
        for xml path ('')),1,1,'') as FromAddress
FROM test o
group by [MID] 
...
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: @nbk, sorry, I did not quite understand your question. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Are there only ever 2 rows for an MID - what if there were 3?

Comment: @Stu it's usually 2 rows but it could be more than 2

Comment: Then it sounds like you'll need dynamicSql as then presumably you'd expect columns FromCountry1... FromCountry2.... how would that work for 2 rows for one MID but several for another MID... This really sounds like something the client application should be dealing with.

Comment: @stu, ok let's take then the fact that we are going to have only 2 rows with the same MID always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the assumption there are no more than 2 rows per `MID` then you can implement a simple row_number() solution.

You need to join one row for each MID to the other, so assign a unique value to each using row_number - there's nothing I can immediately see that indicates which row should be the "second" row - this is assigning row numbers based on the FromCountry - amend as necessary.

I'm not reproducing all the columns here but you get the idea, rinse and repeat for each column.

```
with m as (
  select *, Row_Number() over(partition by Mid order by FromCountry) seq
  from t
)
select m.Mid,
  m.fromcountry, m.fromstate, 
  m2.fromcountry FromCountry1, m2.fromstate FromState1
from m 
join m m2 on m.mid = m2.mid and m2.seq = 2
where m.seq = 1;
```

See [example fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=88b4ccfe1157f8eb58e9d7c8f61ab2b7)